# Way to track "unused" repos using Github API V3?

Tags: git, api, github

I'm working on an auditor that will go through an organization's repos and select repos that can reasonably be deemed as unused. Using pull requests and/or checking the last updated at value against an arbitrary time frame won't return accurate results for what I'm try to accomplish.

I need to find repos that have been lurking away, so to say, from user interaction.

> Is there a way to pull when a repo has been last checked out?
>   If I could find a way to determine when a user did anything to a repo explicitly I could find repos that have been forgotten about and are 'unused' in my case.

Comment: Your method would delete stable code that needs no more updates but is still actively downloaded and used.

Comment: @TheGeorgeous I'm aware of what you're talking about. That's why I said I couldn't just go by updated_at because we have stable code that's been dormant for months that we actively use. I'm just seeing if it's possible to track who clones or checks out a repo